# How To Make Dynamically Generated Page (Via Shortcode) Searchable Inside The Wordpress Website?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a dynamic page generated via short code. My question is how can I make it available for searching inside the wordpress website? Can anybody give some suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. The Very First thing you need to do is to create a shortcode that will return a search form html.
2. This search form should be able to post your search query on the link on site you can also create shortcode for this as well so for eg. in point 1 you created a shortcode called [my_search_form submit_link = 'http://yoursite.com/search-results-page'] and then in point 2 [my_search_form_results]
3. get submit_link and add it to your my_search_form shortcode form action
4. you must create a page for  [my_search_form_results] in that page
5. check if this helps you or let me know in comments